# could not find PyAudio, check installation

Tags: python3, audio-jack, text-to-speech, speech-recognition

I am new to speech recognition and i am trying to use Google Speech API to build a speech to text program. I used the tutorial given in the following link  and the commands within to install dependencies. 
TUTORIAL: https://pythonspot.com/en/speech-recognition-using-google-speech-api/

Commands:

```
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
cd pyaudio
sudo python setup.py install
sudo apt-get installl libportaudio-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev
sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
```

I then was trying to run this dummy script in spyder to see if it was working,

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# Record Audio
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
try:
# for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
# to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, 
#key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
# instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

`

Now when i run this script, i keep getting this error:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-2b39d94ceb5b>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/sanwal092/Desktop/Python/SR/dummy.py', wdir='/home/sanwal092/Desktop/Python/SR')

File "/home/sanwal092/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/sanwal092/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/sanwal092/Desktop/Python/SR/dummy.py", line 14, in <module>
with sr.Microphone() as source:

File "/home/sanwal092/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 78, in __init__
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()

File "/home/sanwal092/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 109, in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")

AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I have looked around on the internet to see if i can work my way around this but nothing i have found seems to work and this is the first time i am working with speech recognition of any sort.

Any help for this problem and any suggestions of how to learn and get better at speech recognition would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message tells you **Could not find PyAudio; check installation**

This list of command in your "tutorial" is wrong, you first install libraries, then compile python module:

> ```
> git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
> cd pyaudio
> sudo python setup.py install
> sudo apt-get installl libportaudio-dev
> sudo apt-get install python-dev
> sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev
> sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
> ```

The correct sequence is:

```
sudo apt-get install libportaudio-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
cd pyaudio
sudo python setup.py install
sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
```

The error is mostly caused by errors in the step `sudo python setup.py install`, which is supposed to install pyaudio. You need to repeat this step. You need to analyze and report errors occurring on this step first before proceeding further.